# Android studio "Failed to resolve: com.adobe.creativesdk"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, adobecreativesdk

I followed a tutorial online to implement adobe creative sdk and end up, when I sync my application I got these two errors
`Error:(65, 14) Failed to resolve: com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.3.94
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>`

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.adobe.creativesdk.image:4.0.0:
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>
```

Did some research but could not solve this new issue previous issue was solved. I'm new to android so how can i solve this issue?

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "${project.rootDir}/creativesdk-repo/release"
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.3.94'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.image:4.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that "${project.rootDir}/creativesdk-repo/release" is the right repo?

Comment: i got it from the tutorial is there any other way?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Even in a completely fresh new app (File -> New Project) in Android Studio, without changing anything it fails. There's no mention of issues on Adobes website, but I'm going to contact them.

Comment: well im going to try it once again if you solve the issue do let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your dependencies block. Note that the line for the Image Editor UI component should be written as:

```
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
```

Before the word `image`, there should be a colon, not a period.

If after that you are still having trouble with the dependencies, [please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32766859/4461425).