# How to import Adobe Creative SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, adobecreativesdk

I'm having trouble getting Android Studio to find Adobe Creative SDK in my app. When I try to build and run my app I get errors.

Here is my code for build.gradle (Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android { 
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.achins.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.5.3'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
failed to resolve : 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.5.3'
failed to resolve : 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New setup**

The Adobe Creative SDK is now offered as a remote Maven repo.

The gradle setup is covered in the [Getting Started guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html).

You can also see functioning gradle code in any of the example Android repos on GitHub. For example, with the Image Editor repo, see:

- [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/code/build.gradle)
- [`app/build.gradle`](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/code/app/build.gradle)

---

**Old setup**

***Note:** this is only for legacy versions of the Creative SDK that were available via direct download. For current versions, use the **New setup** instructions above.*

In order to tell the app where Adobe Creative SDK is in your app's file structure, you'll want to provide the path to the SDK in your `build.gradle` file.

Here is an example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "${project.rootDir}/creativesdk-repo/release" // ADD THE CORRECT LOCATION OF THE CREATIVESDK LIBRARY FILES
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, the `url` path starts at the root directory of the app and looks for a directory called `creativesdk-repo`, then within that, a directory called `release`. 
(If you have added Creative SDK to another location in your app, you will want to edit the `url` above to point to the right place.)

When the maven `url` is correct, your `com.adobe.creativesdk...` dependencies should work. Just be sure you are providing the right version numbers for each part of Creative SDK that you are using!

Answer (score 1):

As of **26/07/2016** Adobe has a public repository that can be used instead of having to host it on our local source code.

A bit hard to find but here they mention it:

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/SetUpTheAdobeMavenRepository.html

Using that repo we can change the dependencies to this:

```
repositories {
    // other repos
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i changed

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

to

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

and it work